# Problem installing skype on ubuntu 12.10 : Error in sound packages

Tags: 12.10, skype, alsa

I tried to install Skype on my ubuntu 12.10 via command line

```
$ sudo apt-get install skype
```

I received this error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libasound2-plugins:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.25) but it is not going to be installed
skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I tried the suggestion,

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get the following error :

```
Unpacking libasound2:i386 (from .../libasound2_1.0.25-3ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-3ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf', which is different from other instances of package libasound2:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-3ubuntu3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Configuration of my ubuntu is as follows :

```
$ uname -a
Linux sumitb-pc 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help me out here ! :)

Comment: the problem is that you updated your ubuntu. DO NOT accept all updates from ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 and you will be OK. u must understand: skype belongs to microsoft now. they are putting out buggy versions so that you badmouth ubuntu and linux.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype), I entered

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

I then got the same errors, which were fixed by entering

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then retyping the 2nd command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

worked like a charm! You can now start skype by typing "skype" into the terminal, or searching for the application in Dash home.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked fine when i [downloaded the package from Skype site](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/downloading.ubuntu64) and installed.